# How can I use the types WORD, UCHAR, ULONG, USHORT in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I have created a Win32 Console Project in Visual Studio 2010. In this project I would like to use an external library with corresponding *headers*. The header files includes variables declared as

- UCHAR
- ULONG
- USHORT
- WORD

stated as above in captitals. Having done very little programming in C++, I don't recognise these types and I do get errors for each line of code containing them:

```
WORD myVariable;
```

Error:

> error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'myVariable'

This is probably a very simple thing, but would like some help to increase my C++ knowledge.

**What do I need to be able to use these types?**

Comment: Please leave a comment if you think the question is bad and needs to be down voted.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These types are defined in `windows.h`, so you need to put `#include <windows.h>` somewhere.

In your case, you probably need to put it in before the header of the external library you're mentioning:

```
#include <windows.h>
// Possibly other stuff here...
#include <external-library.h>
```

Comment: Actually, you only need `windef.h` to get all these types defined.

Comment: `u_short` is undefined with only including `windef.h`, but it works when `windows.h` in included.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the line `#include <windows.h>` in the first line of the source file should fix this error.

If addind the header is still not fixing your issue you might be adding the header in **this order :**

```
#include <any-header-other-than-windows.h>

#include <windows.h>
```

Instead you have to put it in **this order :**

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <any-header-other-than-windows.h>
```